# LUKS container gone due to Windows partition

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, gpt, luks

I plugged a HDD with a LUKS container on it into Windows and opened the Disk Manager. A dialog appeared where I clicked "Format as GPT", not knowing what I was doing. Apparently Windows wasn't able to read the existing LUKS partition and just overwrote it.

Now cryptsetup doesn't recognize the container anymore and my HDD looks like this:

Output of `fdisk -l /dev/sda`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 3,64 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: ST4000DM004-2CV1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A149A5A1-E9D1-4DA3-AE90-8EFD1DB81F44

Device Start End Sectors Size Type
/dev/sda1 34 32767 32734 16M Microsoft reserved

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

Is there any way to restore the container again, or do I have to say goodbye to my data?

Comment: No, there isn't. There some chances if not encrypted but with an encrypted container no way.'

Comment: Unless you have your LUKS header backed up, there is no software way of obtaining the required metadata for decrypting your disk.

Comment: is it possible to create a new header and brute force the key if I still have my password?

Comment: LUKS uses your password only to decrypt the actual key. The actual key is unrelated to the password and cannot be brute-forced.

Comment: Philipp Murry, yes you can try to brute force the key. But given a key size of 512 bit you are most likely not to learn the result based on the available computing power today. As I did not find the key size information in the LUKS spec, I took the 512 from here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/de-de/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/security_hardening/encrypting-block-devices-using-luks_security-hardening

Answer (score 1):

Your case description is lacking the layout of the disk before the incident happened.

If there is an undammaged LUKS header on the disk in question with at least one undammaged key slot that you have the keyword for, recovery might be possible. If that is not the case you have to have an external copy of the LUKS header (including key material). Furthermore it's old location on disk may be needed (I am not sure here) and details of the old partitioning scheme (MBR or GPT) are needed.

There is no "Format as GPT". You either partitioned the disk or formated one of its partitions.
The issue that your Windows was probably asking for partitioning (not formating) as GPT is due to the fact that you assumably used the whole disk for a LUKS partition under Linux without partitioning this disk. Windows then could not find any partitioning scheme, neither MBR nor GPT.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there ANY WAY to restore the container

hmmm, maybe... if you are lucky.

> I plugged a HDD with a LUKS container on it

this does not properly describe the disk state before the butchering took place.

some options for the old disk contents:

1. MS-DOS partition table with LUKS in a partition occupying whole disk.
2. GPT partition table with LUKS in a partition occupying whole disk.
3. LUKS occupying whole disk.

if 1 or 3... game over.

if 2, the disk area available for partitions probably did not change. (GPTs can vary in size, but in practice size is almost always the same.)

the problem is that windows created a 16MB partition. this partition was maybe blanked by windows or maybe the data that was in that area was left alone.

if the area was blanked... game over. this is because the LUKS header and key material is stored at the beginning of LUKS1 volumes, which was overwritten, and without the key material you will never decrypt the data. (LUKS1 on-disk format: https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/cryptsetup/LUKS_docs/on-disk-format.pdf)

(note that LUKS2 has two copies of its metadata, but you were probably using LUKS1.)

unfortunately, i think windows probably wiped these precious 16MB. but it is worth checking that anyway:

`sudo hexdump -C /dev/sda1`

if the header is still there, it should start with magic `LUKS`. otherwise it will be all zeroes. (please tell us.)

if the gods smile at you and the data is still there, you can recreate the partition starting with:

`sudo gdisk /dev/sda`

and following the menus. i am pretty sure gdisk can massage the GPT (eg: delete and create partitions) without touching the data area... **but double check that!** so you can delete the current sda1 partition, then create a new sda1 spanning the whole disk and type it to be LUKS. then check that sda1 still starts at sector 34 **before writing the new partition table back to the disk.**

finally write the new GPT and exit, do a `sudo partprobe /dev/sda` to force the kernel to reread the partition table, and then double check that sda1 still starts with `LUKS`.

of course you might want to take a full backup of the disk before messing with the GPT... if you have where to store the backup.

wish you luck!

Comment: You are ignoring the point of having a backup LUKS header (including key material) and are indicating "game over" too early.

Comment: @Lanchon thanks for the detailed answer! you wrote
"note that LUKS2 has two copies of its metadata, but you were probably using LUKS1." - what makes you think that?

also, unfortunately I think option 3 is the case, since this is how I accessed my data:

cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb sdb-crypt
mount /dev/mapper/sdb-crypt /export/

so the luksOpen command operated on the whole disk :/

Comment: @r2d3 you are absolutely right! go ahead and edit my answer to add that.

Comment: @philipp-murry then yes, option 3 applies to you, whole disk without partitioning. regarding LUKS2, i might be wrong. no way of knowing without knowing which software and options created you LUKS volume. but cryptsetup changed to default to LUKS2 at some point, so there is hope. just "sudo hexdump -C /dev/sda1"; if there is something meaningful in all that data (some text, anything that makes any sense) you are probably using LUKS2 and you might recover. in LUKS1 you would be accessing the data area and should be seeing just random noise.

Comment: @Lanchon hmm, so right now I'm running a hexdump on the LUKS HDD and greping for "LUKS". surprisingly there are actually some findings. could these be coincidental, or might this be meaningful metadata? here's an example (there are more and its still running):

sudo hexdump -C /dev/sda | grep LUKS >>>
ceb74110  69 36 7b 90 bf a6 db 6e  b6 fa 3d 4c 55 4b 53 81  |i6{....n..=LUKS.|

Comment: 4 specific bytes in gigs of data have to happen sooner or later. note that the LUKS magic is actually 6 bytes (search online) and that it is supposed to be aligned at least at a sector boundary. that string is probably coincidental, sorry.